# Add a Lightning Component to Activity Layout

Tags: activities, lightning-components

I want to modify the Send Email Global action and add some custom fields to the layout which is not possible in the standard Global Action. Hence I am trying to create a Lightning Component and add it to the Activities Layout as shown in the picture below.

The Lightning Cmp implements="force:lightningQuickAction" and I have added it to the Pagelayout under 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions', but the cmp is only displayed with other Action. What should I configure to add the Ltng cmp under Activity Layout?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity component does not currently allow you to customize and add your own Email Component replacing the current one. You can post an idea on [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/about)

One workaround you can do is to take the Email Action off by taking off from the page layout in the ***Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions*** sections as shown below

[image]

Once the Email Action is off, build your own custom component and drop it above the standard Activity component or any other place where you think it makes sense.

> It is preferred to keep the Activity component at the bottom because it has built-in ability to scroll.

Comment: Understood. Thanks Mohit. Also the Trailhead link also says 'The Activity tab contains Create a Record quick actions that point to the Event and Task objects'. Upvoted.